# p-400 database system?

Tags: database

has anyone heard of this system? i think it could be S-400 or F-400. google search came up with nothing. is it running oracle? are there many front-end programs for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard of an AS/400 a.k.a iSeries from IBM. Most of them run a DB2 database. I have used Desktop Applications and Web Applications running the front end. Can you tell us what its used for?

Comment: sounds like the right system. Its also used extensively in Financial services